# By-passing Route Guard: Angular 5

Tags: angular

I'm using a route guard which is taking care of all the routes of one of my module. But, in a particular scenario where I know the route I'm accessing is a valid route, I would like to disable the route guard in that case. I'm using:

```
router.navigate(url)
```

for navigating to that url but would like to by pass the route guard in this case. Is there a standard or 'best-practice' way to do this?

Comment: You can add the check for `exceptional valid route` in your guard itself and simply return if that route is found.

Comment: Thanks for the help @AmitChigadani. But cannot do that because the 'id' in the route will be dynamic, and I don't want to remove route guard check from that route completely as it may be invalid when in the future. But the use case I described for sure knows that the route will be valid. So I would like to by pass only in that case.

Comment: You cannot disable route for a scenario. You can completely remove it from the route which you don't want. Suggestion is allow to execute route guard and return true in canActivate method

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom conditions in your guard like so :

```js
canActivate(
  route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, 
  state: RouterStateSnapshot)
: boolean | Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> {
  if (route.url === 'unique/route/not/to/guard') {
    return true;
  } else {
    // ... Your logic
  }
}
```

If your route is complicated (with ids and whatnot), consider using `regexp.exec` to check the validity.

Comment: but can't users simply change the javascript and by-pass the entire routes?